# How can I kill a job that was initiated in another shell (terminal window or tab)?

Tags: shell, terminal, process-management, job-control, jobs

If I begin a process and background it in a terminal window (say `ping google.com &`), I can kill it using `kill %1` (assuming it is job 1).

However if I open another terminal window (or tab) the backgrounded process is not listed under `jobs` and cannot be killed directly using `kill`.

**Is it possible to kill this process from another terminal window or tab?**

Note: I am using the Xfce Terminal Emulator 0.4.3 and bash (although if a solution exists in another common shell but not bash I am open to that as well)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, all you need to know is the process id (PID) of the process. You can find this with the `ps` command, or the `pidof` command.

```
kill $(pidof ping)
```

Should work from any other shell. If it doesn't, you can use ps and grep for ping.

Answer (score 6):

If you type `top` in the another terminal window, it'll list the all the process running. Note the process id of your `job` there, Then press `q` to leave that screen. Then `kill` the process as usual.

Comment: thanks for your answer but `top` does not appear to show all the specific processes running in the shell (e.g., it doesn't show `ping`).  It does give me a PID for the terminal emulator but that kills the terminal emulator as you would expect.

Comment: if you type `top -U yourusername` in terminal, it'll list only the process that you are using.

Comment: awesome!  +1 just for that!  thanks

Comment: while in top, hit k then 15 for a soft-kill (try first), 9 for a hard-kill.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do something like this:

`ps aux | grep $PROCESS | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 " " $11}'`

For example, if $PROCESS="bash", then this is the output from my current session:

```
2683 bash
4481 bash
5695 bash
```

Then I would `kill $PID` for whichever `/bin/bash` I no longer want to be running.

`ps`, `grep` and (optionally) `awk` are helpful for hunting down PIDs to `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

Too easy and not the answer to doing this from shell. But for all of those who are fine with a "workaround":

I switched to that other terminal window that needed to be closed and clicked on "X". It told me that this would kill the process and asked if I really wanted that. `Yes`. That was all I needed.