# Can't see process opened in previous ssh session

Tags: shell, ssh, ps

I have a server, and control it via `ssh`. I am using Windows PowerShell.

1. So I first connect to the server and run my python script in background with

   ```
   python3 -m PKG &
   ```

   If I use `jobs` or `ps`, I can clearly see that it's running ok.
2. Then if I exit this connection and start another one to the same server again, now, if I use `ps` or `jobs` I get nothing. Therefore I can kill my python process only if I remember its PID on the first session.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Try this instead: `nohup python3 -m PKG &`

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58134/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284129/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/509147/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508239/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP 'ps aux' and 'top' are working just fine, thanks!)